# Problem with installation of Steam on CentOS 8

Tags: steam, lib, centos8

After updating graphics card and during installation of Steam on CentOS 8 I get:

```
[root@comp pawel]# yum install epel-release
    Error:
     Problem: conflicting requests
      - nothing provides libxcrypt-compat(x86-32) needed by steam-1.0.0.66-2.el8.i686

[root@comp pawel]# yum install libxcrypt-compat
No match for argument: libxcrypt-compat

[root@comp pawel]# yum install libxcrypt

libxcrypt-4.1.1-4.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
libxcrypt-4.1.1-4.el8.i686 is already installed.
```

I have epel version:

`epel-release-8-8.el8.noarch` is already installed.

How to install Steam?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
yum upgrade
yum update
yum install libxcrypt-compat
yum install epel-release

Comment: Could you please share the console capture

Answer (score 0):

you will get rpm here https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/libxcrypt-4.1.1-4.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

then try rpm –i libxcrypt-4.1.1-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
and then
yum install epel-release

you may get more dependencies. same way

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is broken. The solution is installation of older version.